Why God does what he does?
And God said, Let there be light: and there was light -Genesis 1:3 KJV
The almighty God gets what he desires and what he wants is good indeed. I believe there's a ultimate goal for humanity (as a whole) to achieve and humanity will reach that point eventually. It's just the road and (not the destination) that bothers me.
The unbearable amount of suffering and grief that one experiences during his life is not fair, for example; when Gaza war started I saw a video clip of a dad taking his little daughter's severed body parts which was in a plastic bag to a ruined hospital, desperate, maybe he was hoping he can get his daughter back?
Humanity doesn't have a clue what he's doing, no one is born with a PhD, we all do terrible terrible mistakes and not many have the chance to learn why they should turn the other cheek.
So this thoughts always left me with this question;

Was it necessary to let humans go down this path? What important part are we going to play in this "scenario" of God's creation that made our poor souls worthy of suffering?

And no we did not choose the path of destruction and death, we went that way because we did not knew the ultimate consequences of our actions, If Adam TRULY knew that he's going to cast out of heaven or what not being in heaven is like, would he still have done it?
David, the God chosen prophet committed adultery, he had everything and yet the lust got him. How can one resist sin when David couldn't?

Read the book of Job (it concludes that we are not able to logically or wisely understand what God understands, we can't question his kindness or justice even if our life is so painful that we want to die). Its irrational to try and question God or distrust him.  We do not know what justice is.  But we accuse him of injustice because we are fools. Then consider that God was born for us (for me, for you) to die and suffer that we might be secured into everlasting bliss. Mix this with faith and everything starts to become well. But faith, although the most precious bar of gold, is not easy.

The problem of the existence of evil and suffering, despite there being a benevolent and omnipotent God, has many answers.
Of course, there are the arguments that: Without the possibility of evil, humans would have no free will. However, if God is omnipotent, then surely He could alter the calculus of the universe so that humans could have free will, without the need of the existence of suffering. Other attempts to rationally solve the problem of evil also fall in the same hole: if God is omnipotent, then surely he could remove evil and defy logic anyway.
Instead, arguably the more successful solution is rather the fact that we, as humans, have a tremendously limited scope of wisdom and understanding compared to God, Who is omniscient. Our wisdom is infinitesimally small compared to God's, so small that it approaches zero. Therefore, we cannot really question His authority, His reasoning for why suffering and evil exists. All we really know is that His logic is sound and just. Ultimately, the answer to the problem of evil, is that there is no answer that we, as humans, could possibly comprehend.
To answer the question on, "How could one resist sin when David himself couldn't": Nobody is without sin. Nobody except Jesus Christ. While we definitely should try to resist it, in the end, Jesus Christ's sacrifice on the cross is what paved the way to salvation, so that even with our abundance of sin, we could still find eternal life and unity with God.

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.
